# IsDate Function in SQL evaluates invalid dates as valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running a SQL Statement against imported data from Excel Files.
In this SQL I am checking if the users have entered dates properly by using IsDate function. Since this is a raw data that hasn't been converted yet, all dates are stored in a varchar data type field.

In some circumstances IsDate returns 1 (valid date) when there is clearly an incorrect date format entered by the user.

For Example:

```
07/001/2012

2012-07-002

007/002/2012
```

Any Suggestions on how to handle this problem?

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblImport
 WHERE (ISDATE(dt) = 0 
        AND (dt is not null AND dt <> ''))
```

Thanks!

p.s. Smacking users' did not help.

Comment: No c#. SQL View, which returns records with invalid dates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do a lot of data conversion work and here is a function that I created and use it practically everyday to weed out the bad dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCheckDate
(@InDate nvarchar(50))
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
    BEGIN
        declare @Return DATETIME

        select @return = CASE WHEN ISDATE(@InDate) = 1
                            THEN CASE WHEN CAST(@InDate as DATETIME) BETWEEN '1/1/1901 12:00:00 AM' AND '6/6/2079 12:00:00 AM'
                                    THEN @InDate
                                    ELSE null
                                    END
                            ELSE null
                            END
        return @return
    END
GO
```

Results:

```
SELECT dbo.fnCheckDate('07/001/2012') --> Returns 2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
SELECT dbo.fnCheckDate('2012-07-002') --> Returns 2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
SELECT dbo.fnCheckDate('007/002/2012') --> Returns 2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
SELECT dbo.fnCheckDate('00/002/2012') --> Returns Null
SELECT dbo.fnCheckDate('006/031/2012') --> Returns Null
SELECT dbo.fnCheckDate('') --> Returns Null
```

Comment: +1 but why do you end at 1/2/2030 with SQL smalldatetime goes 2079-06-06

Comment: Because by 2030 I will be long dead and buried (LOL)! All of the data I deal with is historical so I really don't have to worry about future dates but great point.

Comment: The future will be history soon, so you may have to worry about the future.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the `dateformat` first - that worked for me when I was seeing exceptions.

```
set dateformat dmy
select IsDate(<column>)
from Table
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe just check dt's LEN? however, it can not handle cases when the len is valid. maybe input validation should happen in the frontend?

Comment: Input validation was my first line of defense. Unfortunately, since all the data entry is done in Excel files, and we all know how careless users can be, it was simply impossible.