# Convert inconsistent date strings into datetime, ignore bad values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a couple badly managed varchar fields that have a bunch of dates (as well as some garbage data) in them.  Unfortunately dates have been entered into these field in both the month/day/year and day/month/year formats. There are several specific formats including d/m/yy, d.mm.yyyy, d/m/yyyy, dd/mm/yy, etc.

I know storing dates this way is dumb but this is a third party's user defined field, so there is no way to ensure consistent formats.  Here is sample query, [SRC User 5] and [SRC User 6] are the varchar "date" fields:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   [SRC Source code] ,
                        [SRC Description] ,
                        REPLACE([SRC User 5], '.', '/') AS [SRC User 5] ,
                        REPLACE([SRC User 6], '.', '/') AS [SRC User 6] ,
                        [SRC Mailing date] ,
                        [Date of first order] ,
                        [CMP Company]
               FROM     DatabaseName.dbo.Source_LWT
               WHERE    ISDATE([SRC User 5]) = 1
                        AND ISDATE([SRC User 6]) = 1
             )
    SELECT  [SRC Source code] ,
            [SRC Description] ,
            [SRC User 5] AS [Start Date] ,
            [SRC User 6] AS [End Date] ,
            [SRC Mailing date] AS [In Home Date] ,
            [Date of first order] AS [First Order]
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   [SRC User 5] <= GETDATE()
            AND [SRC User 6] >= GETDATE()
            AND YEAR([SRC User 5]) > 13
            AND [CMP Company] = 820
    ORDER BY [SRC User 6]
```

Right now I'm getting an error, I'm thinking caused by the day/month/year format:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

How can I extract the most valid dates from this field as possible, assuming most the values will be month/day/year?

Comment: You can use the [`TRY_CAST()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) and [`TRY_CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) functions.  `PARSE()` and `TRY_PARSE()` might be useful if you know the culture of the date formats.

Comment: I have specified 2008 R2.

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised that's not in 2008 R2.  Well, you can write your own CLR function with `DateTime.TryParse()`

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745650/isdate-function-in-sql-evaluates-invalid-dates-as-valid

Answer (score 0):

---

Thanks For asking:
Please try to replace your query with below, hope its works:

```
WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   [SRC Source code] ,
                    [SRC Description] ,
                    Cast(REPLACE([SRC User 5], '.', '/') as datetime) AS [SRC User 5] ,
                    Cast(REPLACE([SRC User 6], '.', '/') as datetime) AS [SRC User 6] ,
                    [SRC Mailing date] ,
                    [Date of first order] ,
                    [CMP Company]
           FROM     DatabaseName.dbo.Source_LWT
           WHERE    ISDATE([SRC User 5]) = 1
                    AND ISDATE([SRC User 6]) = 1
         )
SELECT  [SRC Source code] ,
        [SRC Description] ,
        [SRC User 5] AS [Start Date] ,
        [SRC User 6] AS [End Date] ,
        [SRC Mailing date] AS [In Home Date] ,
        [Date of first order] AS [First Order]
FROM    cte
WHERE   [SRC User 5] <= GETDATE()
        AND [SRC User 6] >= GETDATE()
        AND right(YEAR([SRC User 5]),2) > 13
        AND [CMP Company] = 820
ORDER BY [SRC User 6]
```

Good Luck

Comment: This did not work; I was given the following error message: "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."  This is most likely due to dates that were entered as dd/mm/yy.